# How to get the results of a HTML select on to a php script

Tags: php, html

Hello: I'm new to PHP and HTML What I want to do is simple: I create a combo box (select) using a php script. The options are created from a list of files in the server machine and it works just fine. However I would like to trigger a second script when the user actually selects something. Here is the code I wrote (minus all the headers and stuff):

```
<form method="post">
<select name="index" onchange="submit">
    <optgroup>
        <option value="nothing"> Elegir un Índice </option>
<?php

//Reading all files in a directory and creating a combo box
$profiles_path = '../perfiles/'; 
$profile_list = scandir($profiles_path);

for ($i = 1; $i <= count($profile_list); $i++){                
    $name = strtok($profile_list[$i], ".");
    if ($name !== false){
        $ext = strtok(".");
        if ($ext === "perf"){
            echo "<option value=\"$name _1\"> $name  </option>";
        }
    }
}
?>
    </optgroup>
</select>
</form>

<?php
$chosen = $_REQUEST['index'];
echo "The selected item is $chosen";
?>
```

Now the question is why is not working. I know is a newbie question but all the results I've  found use JavaScript and I want to avoid doing that.

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: I don't see any function definition for `submit`.

Comment: You cant sumbit the form on change without javascript. If you cant use js, you must add a submit button that the user must press

Comment: Ok, I did not know this. So I need to add a button and execute php code on the onclick of the button? The thing is I can't figure out how to tell the button the script to execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your select tag like following

```
 <select name="index" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

Comment: Perfect!!! This worked!! What is this doing exactly? Becuase it seems like your are calling the submit method of the class form (thinking in old programming) However if this is simple HTML + PHP where is all that defined?

Comment: Great! Thanks! One more question. There should be a way in which I can call a php script (written on a different file) with the onchange, right? Because I've also tried that and it did not work

Comment: You can set this in action attribute in form tag like <form action="script.php">

Comment: Thank you I've tried that before and did not work. But I added action before the method attribute and now it did work!! Thank you again!

Comment: @user792589 just to make sure you are aware, this IS using javascript

Comment: Yes I am aware, thank you. What I meant is that I did not want to write the script in javascript. But since this answer is so simple I will not get picky with it... I'm only started to learn html and php so If I added javascript in the mix, it might be a little too much... Thank you though!